# How to store and retrieve doctor surgery hours in database?

Tags: sql, performance, cassandra, schedule, scylla

How to store doctor working hours in database in order to retrieve free time slots efficiently?

## Approaches

### A. Store rules and exceptions

- doctor defines working hours, e.g. from 9 AM to 3 PM every 30 minutes with 11-12 break
- doctor defines exceptions, e.g. vacation from 1/1/22 to 1/14/22
- doctor defines other exceptions, e.g. tomorrow from 8:30 AM to 12:30 PM
- every time patient wants to make an appointment, server retrieves all rules for doctor from database, analyses them and returns free time slots (e.g. 9 AM, 9:30 AM, 11:30 AM)
- we need prioritized/hierarchical rules and exceptions (they may overlap)?

### B. Fill all time slots in database

- doctor defines working hours, e.g. from 9 AM to 3 PM every 30 minutes with 11-12 break
- if doctor is not available tomorrow, he just removes time slots from tomorrow
- if doctor is available tomorrow from 8:30 AM, he moves a block of time slots
- every time slot = row in database
- every time patient wants to make an appointment, server retrieves all time slots from database for specified period of time and doesn't need to parse rules
- we need tracking changes if we want to undo them?
- we can't populate time slots forever - doctor must plan schedule for specified amount of time (e.g. for next month) or time slots must be generated based on rules (hybrid approach A+B) automatically by a cron job

## Exception examples

- vacation

  - in A we need to make an exception or divide rules into 2 separate (before and after vacation)
  - in B we just remove time slots from database for vacation
- change surgery hours for a period of time, e.g. next week

  - in A similar as above, we make an exception or divide rules
  - in B we change time slots only for next week and others are unchanged
- change surgery hours forever

  - in A similar as above, we make an exception or divide rules
  - in B we change all time slots until the end
- in odd weeks doctor works: Mon, Wed, Fri; in even weeks: Tue, Thu, Sat

  - in A rules become more complicated and parsing may consume more time
  - in B we populate time slots in database only once according to given algorithm
- doctor changes vacation time or removes exception

  - in A he just changes exception time period or deletes and exception
  - in B we populate back time slots (system should track changes to undo them?)
- some slots may be larger (e.g. 1 hour) than others (e.g. 30 minutes), e.g. for a procedure

## Schema examples

### A. Rules and exceptions

```sql
create table rules (
  doctor_id  UUID,
  rule_id    UUID,
  priority   tinyint,   -- example approach to solve overlapping rules
  base_rule  UUID,      -- another approach is a tree of rules
  time_from  timestamp, -- rule is valid from this time (required)
  time_to    timestamp, -- rule is valid until this time (null if forever)
  days       tinyint,   -- bitwise (1-Mon, 2-Tue, 4-Wed, etc)
  app_time   tinyint,   -- appointment time (in minutes, e.g. 30)
  start_hour tinyint,   -- e.g. 8 AM (when he wants to see first patient)
  end_hour   tinyint,   -- e.g. 15 PM (when he leaves surgery / logs out)
  hours      list<time>,-- another approach is a list with all hours (8, 8:30, 9, etc)
  primary key (doctor_id, rule_id)
);
```

We want also exceptions? Probably, but we may also utilize `rules` with priorities or rule tree.

```sql
create table rules (
  doctor_id    UUID,
  exception_id UUID,
  reason       TEXT,
  -- all fields similar as in rules table
  primary key (doctor_id, exception_id)
);
```

### B. Fill all time slots in database

```sql
create table rules (
  doctor_id  UUID,
  patient_id UUID,      -- null if free, not null if booked by a patient
  slot_from  timestamp, -- time slot start time (required, e.g. 1/1/22 9:00)
  slot_to    timestamp, -- time slot end time (required, e.g. 1/1/22 9:30)
  primary key (doctor_id, slot_from)
);
```

Simple! No rule/exception parsing, just fetch and return time slots to patient.

## To sum up

1. Which approach is best?
2. If any approach is bad - why?
3. What would you modify for better performance and flexibility?
4. If approach A, how to handle changes, exceptions, etc. in most efficient way?
5. How is it implemented in already existing calendars/schedules, appointment systems, etc?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing how this table is going to be queried.  Will it really only ever be by `doctor_id`?

Comment: @Aaron: by doctor_id in approach A or by (doctor_id, slot_from) in approach B. We will always include doctor_id in query. We need to display free time slots for specified period of time (e.g. next 5 days) or for a month.